# Cancelling and rescheduling sleep time in uber cadence workflow in java client

Tags: java, cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

How to change the sleep duration in cadence workflow based on a signal? Is it a proper way using java client?

```
private int timeout;

@Override
@WorkflowMethod
public void sleepAndWakeUp(int sleepTimeout) {
    this.timeout = sleepTimeout;
    sleep();
    System.out.println("Woken up after " + this.timeout + " s sleep");
}

private void sleep() {
    int currentTimeout = this.timeout;
    Workflow.await(Duration.ofSeconds(this.timeout), () -> {
        boolean cancelTimer = currentTimeout != this.timeout;
        if(cancelTimer) {
            sleep();
        }
        return cancelTimer;
    });
}

@Override
@SignalMethod
public void snooze(int sleepTimeout) {
    this.timeout = sleepTimeout;
}
```

I have not found other possibility to cancel and reschedule a workflow sleep timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code from the [Temporal Java Samples](https://github.com/temporalio/temporal-java-samples/tree/master/src/main/java/io/temporal/samples/updatabletimer):

```
public final class UpdatableTimer {

  private long wakeUpTime;
  private boolean wakeUpTimeUpdated;

  public void sleepUntil(long wakeUpTime) {
    this.wakeUpTime = wakeUpTime;
    do {
      wakeUpTimeUpdated = false;
      Duration sleepInterval = Duration.ofMillis(this.wakeUpTime - Workflow.currentTimeMillis());
      if (!Workflow.await(sleepInterval, () -> wakeUpTimeUpdated)) {
        break;
      }
    } while (wakeUpTimeUpdated);
  }

  public void updateWakeUpTime(long wakeUpTime) {
    this.wakeUpTime = wakeUpTime;
    this.wakeUpTimeUpdated = true;
  }

  public long getWakeUpTime() {
    return wakeUpTime;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Yes, the annotations WorkflowMethod and SignalMethod are on implementation only for the sake of this example code